# How to fix ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence in a hibernate project intellij

Tags: hibernate, maven, intellij-idea

I dont know what im doing wrong :C please help me c:

```
public static void main (String[] arg){
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PruebaPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }
```

I readed that might be the dependencies but i have the hibernate and javax dependency added

Version of the JDK:1.8.0

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
        <artifactId>bom-all</artifactId>
        <version>${version.thorntail}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.16</version>
      </dependency>



    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

The javax dependency its at the end

```
</build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And here the Exception when i run the project.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
    at utn.dlc.Prueba.rest.Program.main(Program.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the maven dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
```

To provide for the missing class

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did what you told me and now it throws me this in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service

Comment: This could be due to wrong password, proper dialect/driver or some dependency missing. Please look at other threads in SO.